# Hypertext with comments?

Tags: hyperref

I want to pick up an `hyperref` with the drawback that it contains `%`

```
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lept%C3%B3n
```

Is there a way to kick `%` out?

Comment: There is no need to kick something out ;-) `\url` should work. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3):

The macros `\href` and `\url` change the category code of `%` to get of its comment behavior:

```
\url{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lept%C3%B3n}
\href{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lept%C3%B3n}{Lept\'on}
```

But inside the argument of another macro, this will not work, because then the percent is already read as comment char, before the inner `\url` or `\href` is executed. Since the argument is already read, the category changes will come too late. Therefore `hyperref` also provides `\%` to get the percent character in the URL, e.g.:

```
\footnote{\url{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lept\%C3\%B3n}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\url` and other commands from the `hyperref` package take care of its input paths and the characters. So `%` should be no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\url{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lept%C3%B3n}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, it works. Thanx

Comment: ... I have to say that it keeps reading it as a comment... I tried verbatim but is a mess

Comment: @LyonBuster: You did not write that it's inside a comment

Comment: is not a comment, it was a large hyperref which have that %

Comment: also, \% works perfectly

Comment: @LyonBuster: Sorry, I meant `macro`, not comment